# What would the regex be for this?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
videos/000/000/021/10f43ddb37472ee4bb57_original.m4v
```

I need this part:

```
videos/000/000/021/
```

So format is:

```
videos/{3 digit number (000-999)}/{3 digit number (000-999)}/{3 digit number (000-999)}/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
videos/(\d{3}/){3}
```

Meaning: `"videos/"` followed by three digits and a forward slash three times

Answer (score 1):

```
^videos/(\d{3})/(\d{3})/(\d{3})/
```

Explanation:

- `\d` matches a digit.
- `{3}` requires three of the previous item.
- `^` anchors the match at the beginning of the string so "videos/111/222/333/" matches but "othervideos/111/222/333/" does not.
- Parentheses can be used to capture the three numbers so you can examine them in a later step; in some languages they'll be available as `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
videos/([0-9]{3}/){3}
```

If your regex flavor needs forward slash delimiters,

```
/videos\/([0-9]{3}\/){3}/
```